# Any reasons to use "SET search_path" if use schema-qualified names everywhere in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I googled but I couldn't find answer on this question: does it makes sense to use  `SET search_path` in case of use schema-qualified names everywhere in Postgresql.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No, if you truly use schema-qualified names everywhere including for operators, then the `search_path` is not used, and you might as well `SET search_path TO pg_catalog` only. (`pg_catalog` will *always* be part of the *effective search path*, but you might as well make it explicit.)

Are you sure that you use schema-qualified names everywhere, including things like `2 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.+) 2`?

As an aside, in case you're interested, I recently started doubting my own habit of using schema-qualified almost everywhere and did a deep dive into the [pros and cons of the `search_path`](https://blog.bigsmoke.us/2022/11/11/postgresql-schema-search_path). (Yes, besides brevity, there are valid use cases for the `search_path`.)